# window.location.href not redirecting ONLY to a certain site

Tags: javascript, redirect

i am not a developer, just a designer with a bit of coding knowledge, so please bear with me.

I was trying to put a redirect with countdown from a WP webpage to another webpage on different server. There are lots of pluggings that do that but don't have a stop button, so i tried with JavaScript.
The script works fine on every link i try except the one i need, so i am out of ideas. Please help.
Thank you.

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var time_left = 20;
    var cinterval;
    var timestatus=1;
    var redirect="http://someexamplesite.com/";
    function time_dec(){
        time_left--;
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = time_left;
        if(time_left <=0){
                window.location.href = redirect;
    }
    }
    function resumetime()
    {
        //time_left = 20;
        clearInterval(cinterval);
        cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
    }
    function defaultstart()
    {
        time_left = 20;
        clearInterval(cinterval);
        cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
    }
    function stopstarttime()
    {
        if(timestatus==1)
    {
        clearInterval(cinterval);
        document.getElementById('stopbutton').value="Start";
        timestatus=0;
    }
        else
    {
        clearInterval(cinterval);
        cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
        document.getElementById('stopbutton').value="Stop";
        timestatus=1;
    }
    }
    defaultstart();
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
</HEAD>
<body>
    Redirecting In <span id="countdown">20</span>.
    <INPUT TYPE="button" value="stop" id="stopbutton"   onclick="stopstarttime()">
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: `The script works fine on every link i try except the one i need` - clearly there's something "wrong" with the one you "need" - and as you haven't shared the link you "need", it's going to be hard interesting if anyone can help

Comment: So what is the link you are trying to redirect to? Is it public?

Comment: As it is now, the script works.  Maybe the link you're trying to use has an error in it.  Just in case, you could try `window.location.href = "' + redirect + '"`;

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console when it fails?

Comment: @sideroxylon, `location.href` expects a valid URI, and a valid URI is not enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Happy to get some feedback. The link is a page on of big company, so i tought it's safe not to share. Actually do'no i'l have to ask if can't get other ideas. From the link is on a secure server and looks like:

Comment: "https://subdomain.bigcompany.de/site.owner/" if i acces it directly via browser it loads just fine. After this script is done counting i see in the bar (down) that it is repeatedly reloading with "waiting for https..." also tried to replace window.location.href with window.location.replace with no luck. I change the link to whatever other link and it works like a charm. I taught i was using some unallowed command and i get a deny because of some security protection that i don't know of.